# Accessing AngularJS variable in slickgrid

Tags: angularjs, slickgrid

I have integrated SlickGrid with my Angular JS application. Earlier I was populating the Grid Data with plain hardcoded javascript code[see below]. But now I need to get the grid data from REST service which is invoked in my angular Js Controller and saved in an object array. How do I access a variable[array] defined in angular js inside my SlickGrid javascript code.

I tried replacing 'data' below with the array defined in angular js code but it's not working. Can anyone please help me here.

```
    $(function () {
/*  need to comment out this code once I can use the array defined in angular Js */
        var data = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
          data[i] = {
            title: "Task " + i,
            duration: "5 days",
            percentComplete: Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
            start: "01/01/2009",
            finish: "01/05/2009",
            effortDriven: (i % 5 == 0)
          };
        }

        grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
      })
```

Update: This is my slickgrid code. I am invoking a REST service to get the data in $scope.data1 and then using it to populate the slickgrid but I am getting an empty slickgrid. But if I hardcode the data in $scope.data1 , it works. What I am missing? Can anyone please help me. I have spent an entire day on this issue.

```
$scope.populateGridData  =  function()

        FetchPopulation.get({id:1} , function(response ) {

            $scope.data1 = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < response.PopulationList.population.length; i++)
                $scope.data1[i] = {
                    firstName: response.PopulationList.population[i].firstName,
                    lastName: response.PopulationList.population[i].lastName,
                    designation: response.PopulationList.population[i].designation,
                    department: response.PopulationList.population[i].department,
                    salary: response.PopulationList.population[i].salary,
                    rating: response.PopulationList.population[i].rating,
                    joiningDate: response.PopulationList.population[i].joiningDate,
                    employeeId: response.PopulationList.population[i].employeeId,
                    employeeType: response.PopulationList.population[i].employeeType,
                    manager: response.PopulationList.population[i].manager,
                    permanent: (i % 5 == 0),
                    percentComplete: Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
                };
/*
            $scope.data1= [{employeeId:"12345", firstName: "aaa", lastName: "bbb" , designation:"Business Analyst" , department:"FSI" ,
                salary:"120000",rating:"1" , joiningDate:"12/8/2013" , employeeType:"permanent" , manager:"aaaa" }];
*/

            var grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", $scope.data1, $scope.columns, $scope.options);

            $scope.grid.setSelectionModel(new Slick.CellSelectionModel());


        });
    };
```

Comment: does your data get filled in the controller $scope? You know the data has to be valid JSON

Comment: yes the data is valid Json and I am filling it on $scope.dataAngular.How do I use this 'dataAngular' in slickgrid code?

Comment: have you tried to just build the slickgrid object with your angular data... `grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", $scope.dataAngular, columns, options);` ... are you using the SlickGrid DataView?

Comment: Yes I am doing exactly this   grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", $scope.data1, columns, options); But I get an empty grid in output. I am not using DataView.

Comment: when I had to call one of my angular service from my slickgrid code. I had to use angular.injector , do I need to use something similar to access variables defined in angular?

Comment: I'm not sure about plain SlickGrid without using DataView object, though on my side I'm using the DataView object and I just need to pass the $scope.data to Slick.Grid object and it works. Maybe you should try the DataView, it has so much benefits and feature using it (like grouping for example)

Comment: @ghiscoding  -  I have added my code. Can you please check it once and tell me if you can find the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Did you type by hand the commented line there? Because it's not valid JSON, everything has to be escape `[{employeeId:"12345"` should be `[{"employeeId":"12345",...` and even if it's not that, your dataset seems wrong. I am not using SlickGrid without the DataView as you are doing but if you take the basic example and copy this piece of code (pulled from [SlickGrid example2](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/examples/example2-formatters.html):

```
$(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      var d = (data[i] = {});

      d["title"] = "<a href='#' tabindex='0'>Task</a> " + i;
      d["duration"] = "5 days";
      d["percentComplete"] = Math.min(100, Math.round(Math.random() * 110));
      d["start"] = "01/01/2009";
      d["finish"] = "01/05/2009";
      d["effortDriven"] = (i % 5 == 0);
    }

    grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
})
```

it will most probably work... Try this piece out before going back to your code, but I strongly suspect your JSON result might not be valid as you think it is... now after you tried the basic sample and you go back to your code, you could try to validate your JSON output by going here: [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) just copy+paste your JSON in there and click validate.

Comment: Thanks @ghiscoding!! I have solved the issue. There were couple of mistakes I did which is not visible in my question.Thanks for JSONLint and pointing out that my json was wrong. I was not aware about it.